# Facebook API error 'invalid album id' when uploading a photo

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to add a large picture to a fan page that I just created.

This code works :

```
$picUrl = 'http://myurl/test.jpg';
$photoId = $facebook->api("/me/photos","POST",array('url'=>$picUrl,'message'=>"status message","access_token"=>$token));
```

But this one doesn't work :

```
$picUrl = 'http://myurl/test.jpg';
$photoId = $facebook->api("/MYALBUMID/photos","POST",array('url'=>$picUrl,'message'=>"status message","access_token"=>$token));
```

I got this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#120) Invalid album id

I have search a lot on other thread.
I think its about the token.
But the token seems to work because I can post with feed/links on my fan page...

Do you know what's wrong? :)

Thanks a lot !

Comment: The title is very misleading. Anyways, the error is quite clear, the albumId is not correct. Did you checked `/Album_id` ?

Comment: I fixed the title to describe the problem more accurately.

Comment: Yes I think the albumid is correct. when I go there graph.facebook.com/ALBUMID 

I got this :

    {
       "id": "ALBUMID",
       "from": {
          "category": "Community",
          "name": "MYPAGETITLE",
          "id": "PAGEID"
       },
       "name": "test",
       "description": "test",
       "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=ALBUMID&id=PAGEID&aid=10737...",
       "cover_photo": "199487...",
       "count": 2,
       "type": "normal",
       "created_time": "2013-09-20T11:11:55+0000",
       "updated_time": "2013-09-20T11:34:04+0000",
       "can_upload": false
    }

Answer (score 0):

The `access_token` generated to manage a user is not the same as the `access_token` needed to manage a page.

To get an access token for a page:

```
me/accounts?fields=access_token,name
```

Then, use the page access token to run the query:

```
$facebook->api("/MYALBUMID/photos","POST",
                array('url'=>$picUrl,'message'=>"status message","access_token"=>$token));
```

Comment: Yes I asked : &scope=manage_pages,publish_stream,email,publish_actions

As I said, I can user /PAGEID/feed in order to post simple links or message, it works

Comment: Ok. Answer updated. But are you posting messages as your personal account or as the page administrator? This is different! Everyone can post a message on a page feed whereas only the administrators of the page can add pictures to one of the page albums.

Comment: I have a php page witch create the access token for the page with appid & app secret. So I have one token registered in my database. Is there a way to be sure that the token I have is available for that page ? thx

Comment: Well, When I go on this page : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/

I can see all access_token for my pages.
And for the actual page, the token is the same as the token in my database, so the token I use to make the call

Comment: The access token you see on this page is the one of the **app** you are coding right now, it isn't the page! Anyway, you can check whether the access token you got for the page is valid, by doing: `https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAB7h4mnDVmxxO...` and see if it indeed shows your page information.

Comment: HEre is the 2 pages I use :

http://codepad.org/rh4tcH8j (generate token for page & store in db)
http://codepad.org/CiPTFVnp (make the call)

Comment: Then you are not using the right access token, the one that you should have gotten through `me/accounts?fields=access_token,name`! I see in your files that you didn't even query `me/accounts` as I stated in my initial answer. Are you reading what I'm trying to explain? :-)

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?fields=access_token,name

=>

{
   "error": {
      "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}

Comment: Why would this query dispense you from indicating the access token?

Comment: So I did :

$facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
echo $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$facebook->api('/me/accounts', 'GET', array('access_token' => $access_token));

=> An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

BUT my token apears : 7226...44417222|c1dc36f96...9439994f8c71354694a

Comment: Ok I get it working OUFF folowing the page : http://docgecko.com/rails/fb_graph/gem/facebook/2011/12/22/creating-facebook-account-and-page-access-tokens-for-the-fb_graph-gem.html. Thanks a lot Stéphane Bruckert for helping me ! I'll now understand about access_token :p